# .each is not working as i thought

Tags: jquery, each

i have multiple outer divs called h_block contain inner divs called h_block_intro and i want to make bottom border for the first inner divs in each h_block div but it works for the first div only  http://jsfiddle.net/2GkW8/

html
    
    
     text

```
<div class="h_block_intro">
 text   
</div>
<div class="h_block_intro">
 text   
</div>

<div class="h_block_intro">
 text   
</div>
</div>
<div class="h_block">
<div class="h_block_intro">
 text   
</div>

<div class="h_block_intro">
 text   
</div>
<div class="h_block_intro">
 text   
</div>

<div class="h_block_intro">
 text   
</div>
</div>
```

js (inside document ready)

```
$(".h_block .h_block_intro:eq(0), .h_block .h_block_intro:eq(1)").each(function(){
    $(this).css("border-bottom","1px dashed #952BE8");
});
```

css

```
.h_block{
width:160px; height:122px; float:left; border:1px solid red; margin-left:10px;
}
.h_block_intro{
width:160px; height:30px; float:left; background-color:orange;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to use each for `.css()` as it's applied to the whole collection by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your javascript function into :

```
$(".h_block").find(".h_block_intro:eq(0)").css("border-bottom","1px dashed #952BE8");
```

Here is fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/2GkW8/12/

Comment: There's no need for an each() iteration.

Comment: yeah. just recognized. improved my answer. Thanks @isherwood

Answer (score 1):

The index values as you're using them are absolute:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2GkW8/4

To demonstrate further, I've broken your approach down to make it work:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/2GkW8/8

```
$(".h_block").find(".h_block_intro:eq(0)")
    .css("border-bottom", "1px dashed #952BE8");
```

Comment: Updated to simplify further.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".h_block .h_block_intro:nth-child(0), .h_block .h_block_intro:nth-child(1)").each(function(){
    $(this).css("border-bottom","1px dashed #952BE8");
});
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/2GkW8/2/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context but have you considered CSS pseudo selectors?

You could use

```
.h_block_intro:first-child {
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #952BE8;
}
```

Like this http://jsfiddle.net/2GkW8/16/